# Canonical format to present email evidence in a pleading (petition)

Tags: pleadings

Defendant emails are to be presented in a pleading:  conciseness is the key feature of the effective pleading. I am seeking canonical examples and elements of effective &concise pleadings.

Is there a equivalent of Strunk & White or the Chicago Manual of Style for pleadings?  Not sure if these books would help to write a concise pleading wherein the exhibits / evidence are email.

Comment: The title mentions email but the body does not. How does email relte to your question?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Good question.   Evidence is in the form of email, wherein the defendants document their transgressions.

Comment: Besides the format of a pleading you might need to research what testimony might be needed to validate/corroborate the email itself.

Comment: Agree with @GeorgeWhite. The larger concern is how to present the email so it's admissible, which is not a style question but an evidentiary one. If you're attaching it to a pleading, you probably want to make it an exhibit to an affidavit that authenticates it.

Comment: Good comments / advice.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent of Strunk & White would be [The Redbook](https://www.westacademic.com/Garners-The-Redbook-A-Manual-on-Legal-Style-4th-9781642422672). The equivalent to the Chicago Manual of Style would be [The Bluebook](https://www.legalbluebook.com/).

Comment: I hadn't heard of "The Redbook" until now, but I would agree that Bryan A. Garner is the foremost authority in the U.S. on legal writing style. This said, any reasonable, consistently applied format would be acceptable. Also, font, margins, and the like are usually governed by court rule (F.R.C.P. 10 https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/frcp/rule_10 in federal trial courts in civil actions along with parallel local court rule) and state rule of civil procedure 10 in states that have rules numbered parallel to the federal ones. See, e.g. Colorado Rule of Civil Procedure 10.